# How would I write this to execute on a single subfolder

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server

Currently it runs all inbox rules against the inbox.
Sorry if I've missed anything obvious, I'm not fluent in VBA
I know I can add IncludeSubFolders:=True however I only wish to run the script on one subfolder.

```
Sub Inbox()
Dim st As Outlook.Store
Dim myRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim rl As Outlook.Rule
Dim count As Integer
Dim ruleList As String

' get default store (where rules live)
Set st = Application.Session.DefaultStore
' get rules
Set myRules = st.GetRules

' iterate all the rules
For Each rl In myRules
    ' determine if it’s an Inbox rule
    If rl.RuleType = olRuleReceive Then
    ' if so, run it
        rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True
        count = count + 1
        ruleList = ruleList & vbCrLf & rl.Name
    End If
Next

' tell the user what you did
ruleList = "These rules were executed against the Inbox: " & vbCrLf & ruleList
MsgBox ruleList, vbInformation, "Macro: RunAllInboxRules"

Set rl = Nothing
Set st = Nothing
Set myRules = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set the optional Folder parameter to the sub-folder of the Inbox.  You of course still need to add some code to get the specific Folder object from the Inbox's Folder.Folders collection.